# Controller variable null in js

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a variable whos value i am setting on click of command button. I have a 2nd command button and i want to use the new value of the variable set previously.
vf:

```
  <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn btn btn-primary" id="generate"  action="{!generate}" value="Generate" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:5px;" reRender="" oncomplete="return false;"/>
  <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn-primary" onclick=" if(!fncValidate()){return false;}" id="vieweLineStatusButton" value="Submit" disabled="false" reRender="" oncomplete="return false;" />
```

script:

```
<script>
    function fncValidate(){
    var one = '{!first}';
        alert(one);
     return true;   
    }
</script>
```

apex:

```
 public String first{get; set;}
 public PageReference generate(){
 first = '1111';
 return null;

 }
```

i am always getting null in my js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that given script code is evaluated only once during page load. That cause JS to be executed only once, so as long as **first** in controller is not set in constructor or getter, then it will be assigned to JavaScript variable **one** as null, and will not be updated.

There are few ways to keep those records in sync. One of that is using **reRender** action to rerun JS code after controller method execution, after visualforce state got updated apex variable from server. Personally I do not like that method because it can easily cause JavaScript issues, which I prefer to stay clear and concise.

Another option will be using `<apex:inputHidden />` and JS to get updated variable from that. Nice example can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/getting-value-of-inputhidden-to-javascript).

In your case, that may look like next (JS pseudocode):

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:form>
  <!--INITIAL CODE -->
 <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn btn btn-primary" id="generate"  action="{!generate}" value="Generate" 
                     style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:5px;" reRender="" oncomplete="return false;"/>
 <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn-primary" onclick=" if(!fncValidate()){return false;}" 
                     id="vieweLineStatusButton" value="Submit" disabled="false" reRender="" oncomplete="return false;" />
<!--END INITIAL CODE -->
<apex:inputHidden value="{!first}" id="veryUniqInputId"/>
<script>
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

   function fncValidate() {
     var one =  $j("element[id$='veryUniqInputId']").val();
     alert(one);
     return true;   
   }
  </script>
</apex:form>
```

There are other options, like remoting or web service execution, but that require more logic to be implemented.